# Should I divide by f or sqrt(f) to generate pink noise?

Tags: python, signal-processing

I created the code below to generate pink or brown noise. It is mostly based on the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67127726/2369000. I am not sure about the exponent in the pink() and brown() functions. I know that pink noise is supposed to have amplitude scaling with 1/f, so I divided by f in my code. I also used a linear regression to calculate the slope of the log-log plot, and got -1, which is expected. However, in the other answer that I linked, the author used sqrt(f) for pink noise and f for brown noise. Is my code right or is the other code right?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def pink(f):
    return 1/np.where(f == 0, float('inf'), f)
def brown(f):
    return 1/np.where(f == 0, float('inf'), f**2)
def white(f):
    return 1

N = 10000
X_time_domain = np.random.randn(N)
X_freq_domain = np.fft.rfft(X_time_domain);
scaling = pink(np.fft.rfftfreq(N))
# Normalize S (optional)
# scaling = scaling / np.sqrt(np.mean(scaling**2))
X_freq_domain = X_freq_domain * scaling
X_time_domain = np.fft.irfft(X_freq_domain)

freq = np.fft.rfftfreq(N)
amplitude = np.abs(np.fft.rfft(X_time_domain))
# remove 0
freq = freq[1:]
amplitude = amplitude[1:]
plt.loglog(freq, amplitude)
plt.show()

from scipy import stats
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(np.log(freq), np.log(amplitude))
print(slope)
```

[image: Output]

Comment: This might be better suited on a math or science stack exchange site. This issue does not really revolve around a programming issue, but rather modeling the scientific/mathematical problem.

Comment: okay, I'll move it to the math stackexchange

Comment: I tried posting it and they said it was a programming question, not a math question. I'm just going to leave both up and delete the one that isn't answered. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4506967/should-i-divide-by-f-or-sqrtf-to-generate-pink-noise-python-code?noredirect=1#comment9461193_4506967

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pink noise, the *power* spectral density is proportional to 1/f.

Since power is proportional to amplitude<sup>2</sup>, that means that the average *amplitude* around a given frequency is proportional to 1/sqrt(f).

Comment: You beat me with it. Quite a common misunderstanding, power and amplitude spectra are often confused.